# 3 psi on main before drop to 1/2"

Tags: water-pressure

The psi on the main Mobile Home Park side is 3

This is before the from to 1/2" pipe leading into my homes main.

The old pipe is galvanized, 3/4 to 1/2" I believe.

In repiping all the water lines to 2 baths 2 toilets 2 kitchen sinks & washer -
What would be the the best pipe size solution to get the most water pressure?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your incoming water pressure from the utility is 3 PSI? Are you sure? Usually 30 PSI is considered on the low end.

Comment: 30 PSI or 3 Bar (43.5 PSI) are far more likely, especially if you are not simultaneously noting that your water pressure is absurdly low, which 3 PSI is.

Comment: maybe you didn't pay the water bill and they shut off your water, but they have a leaky valve